# Model Class Not Found with Codeception and Laravel4

Tags: php, testing, laravel-4, codeception

I am following the course of tutsplus: https://tutsplus.com/lesson/laravel-gotchas/ but I have an error in this lesson: https://tutsplus.com/lesson/laravel-gotchas/

The error is that I'm am trying to create a object of type Post (Post is a model in Laravel) but I have the next message when run codeception tests:

```
laravel : codecept run
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v1.8.3
Powered by PHPUnit 3.7.31 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Acceptance Tests (1) ------------------------------------------------
Trying to perform actions and see result (SigninCept.php)       Ok
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Functional Tests (2) -------------------------------------------------



FATAL ERROR. TESTS NOT FINISHED.
Class 'Post' not found 
in laravel/app/tests/functional/PostCest.php:9
```

This is my test PostCest.php

```
<?php
use \TestGuy;

class PostCest
{

    public function _before()
    {
    }

    public function _after()
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function tryToTest(TestGuy $I) {
       $post = new Post;
       $post->title = 'Some title';
       $post->body = 'Some title';
       $post->save();
   }

}
```

And this is my Post class:

```
<?php

class Post extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, there is no class called 'Post' defined in your application.

Where do you believe this class should be?

You may want to check to make sure you haven't namespaced the post class, and need to do something like

```
new \Namespace\Post;
```

Edit: Trying changing post.php to Post.php. I had an issue some months ago where my server didn't deal well with capitals in file names

Comment: I have a Post class in models/Post.php

Comment: try changing the file name to post.php I had an issue some months ago where my server didn't like capitals in filenames

Comment: Don't work. I have the same problem: FATAL ERROR. TESTS NOT FINISHED.
Class 'Post' not found